# Solution for SPOJ AGGRCOW

Tags: c++

I have the folowing problem:

> Farmer John has built a new long barn, with N (2 <= N <= 100,000)
>   stalls. The stalls are located along a straight line at positions
>   x1,...,xN (0 <= xi <= 1,000,000,000).
>
> His C (2 <= C <= N) cows don't like this barn layout and become
>   aggressive towards each other once put into a stall. To prevent the
>   cows from hurting each other, FJ wants to assign the cows to the
>   stalls, such that the minimum distance between any two of them is as
>   large as possible. What is the largest minimum distance?
>
> Input
>
> t – the number of test cases, then t test cases follows. 
>   * Line 1: Two space-separated integers: N and C
>   * Lines 2..N+1: Line i+1 contains an integer stall location, xi
>
> Output
>
> For each test case output one integer: the largest minimum distance.
>
> Example

Input:

> 1
>   5 3
>   1
>   2
>   8
>   4
>   9

Output:

> 3 Output details:
>
> FJ can put his 3 cows in the stalls at positions 1, 4 and 8, 
>   resulting in a minimum distance of 3.  Submit solution!

My approach was to pick some pair which has a certain gap and check if there are enough elements in the array to satisfy the need of all the cows.
To find these elements,I used binary search.

When I find an element , I reset my left to mid so I can continue based on the number of cows left.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

int bsearch(int arr[],int l,int r,int gap , int n,int c){
    int stat = 0;
    for (int i = 1;i <= c; ++i) {
        while(l <= r) {
            int mid = (l+r)/2;
            int x = n+(i*gap);
            if (arr[mid] > x && arr[mid-1] < x) {
                l = mid;
                ++stat;
                break;
            }
            if(arr[mid] < x) {
                l = mid + 1;
            }
            if (arr[mid] > x) {
                r = mid - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (stat == c) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }

}
int calc(int arr[],int n , int c) {
    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = i+1;j < n; ++j) {
            int gap = arr[j] - arr[i];
            if (gap > max) {
                if (bsearch(arr,j,n-1,gap,arr[j],c) == 0) {
                    max = gap; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return max;
}
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    int t , n ,c;
    cin >> t;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < t; ++i) {
        cin >> n >> c;
        int arr[n];
        for (int z = 0 ; z < n; ++z) {
            cin >> arr[z];
        }
        sort(arr,arr+n);
        //Output;
        int ans = calc(arr,n,c);
        cout << ans;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Problem Page:
https://www.spoj.com/problems/AGGRCOW/

Comment: Fyi, there's this thing called [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) provided by the standard library, the use of which would throw about 1/3rd of this code away.

Comment: @WhozCraig I know but it wouldn't take a number EQUAL to the value that I am looking for.

Comment: Did you *read* the link I provided ? `lower_bound` finds the first element that is *not* less than (i.e. is greater **or equal**) to the search element. After return, test the iterator for (a) non-sequence end and (b) equal. Or maybe I just misunderstand that function? One sees `bsearch` and, you know, thinks "binary *search*".

Comment: Oh sry, I stand corrected.Although I could make it work ,what is wrong in the approach illustrated in my code if its fundamentally the same thing?

Comment: Stuff like `int arr[n]` isn't valid C++, because [C++ doesn't have variable length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/9254539). Your code only compiles because of a GCC non-standard extension. You should use an `std::vector` instead to make your code portable and avoid blowing out the stack.

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong. It runs in at least `O(n^2)` because of the nested loop in your `calc()` function, which is too slow. The solution involves using a binary search in a different way.